# Compute the covariance of 2 random variables and answer if the variables are independent

Tags: probability, random-variables, covariance

> In an urn there are 5 white balls and 4 black balls. One ball is
>   extracted from the urn and is replaced with a ball of the opposite
>   collor. Then a new ball is extracted. $X$ represents the number of
>   white balls extracted and $Y$ the number of black balls extracted.
>
> (c) Compute the covariance of the 2 variables. Are these 2 variables
>   independent?

In the official solution:

The distribution of these 2 variables is:

$$X:\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1  & 2 \\ \frac{12}{81} & \frac{49}{81} & \frac{20}{81} \end{matrix}\right)
$$

$$Y:\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1  & 2 \\ \frac{20}{81} & \frac{49}{81} & \frac{12}{81} \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Then

$$XY:\left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1  \\ \frac{32}{81} & \frac{49}{81} \end{matrix}\right)
$$

Then

$$E[XY] = \frac{49}{81}$$ and $$cov(X, Y) = \frac{49}{81}  - \frac{89}{28} * \frac{73}{81}$$

What I don't understand is how did he get the distribution for $XY$.

Comment: The author actually implicitly refer to the joint distribution of $X, Y$ (because this is simple enough so he did not put that out explicitly). Can you find that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $2$ balls are extracted in total, $X+Y=2$, so although the distributions for $X$ and $Y$ are written like marginal distributions, they actually tell you the joint distribution, since the value of $X$ determines the value of $Y$ and vice versa. (This also explains the symmetry between the two distributions.)

Now $0\cdot2=2\cdot0=0$ and $1\cdot1=1$, so $P(XY=1)=P(X=Y=1)$ and $P(XY=0)$ is the complement.